# How to copy an Influx measurement to new measurement in different database?

Tags: influxdb

Trying to copy one measurement data from different measurement in different influxDB, not finding any queries
I have query to copy from one measurement to other measurement in same database but need different database.

Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the database name within the INTO clause. see https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-into-clause.

`INTO <database_name>.<retention_policy_name>.<measurement_name>`           Writes data to a fully qualified measurement. Fully qualify a measurement by specifying its database and retention policy.

`INTO <database_name>..<measurement_name>`         Writes data to a measurement in a user-specified database and the DEFAULT retention policy.

Comment: @Murthi - please mark the answer as correct if it helped you

Comment: SELECT * INTO destination_DB..measurement FROM source_DB..measurement group by *
-

(This worked perfectly!)

Comment: @Murthi - please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . You should mark the answer as accepted, thanks

Comment: thank for your inputs, i'm new to StackOverflow, now i have checked for your answer, thank u once again :)

Comment: @Murthi Another possibility, if you need a constant ETL from one database to another, is to use Kapacitor.